# system.net.webexception se ha terminado la conexión error inesperado de envío, C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, excepciones

Estoy tratando de conectarme a la API de freshdesk, solo que al momento de iniciar mi proyecto me marca una exception que es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ese Webexception me lo marca en la siguiente linea de codigo:

```
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
```

En mi clase CreateTicket tengo el siguiente fragmento de código:

```
string fdDomain = "MY_DOMAIN"; // your freshdesk domain
        string apiKey = "MY_API_KEY";
        string apiPath = "/api/v2/tickets"; // API path
        string json = "{\"status\": 2, \"priority\": 1, \"email\":\"erojas@boz.mx\",\"subject\":\"test\",\"description\":\"confirm whether received\"}";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://" + fdDomain + ".freshdesk.com" + apiPath);
        //HttpWebRequest class is used to Make a request to a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI).  
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest. 
        request.Method = "POST";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest. 
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        string authInfo = apiKey + ":X"; // It could be your username:password also.
        authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
        request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;

        //Get the stream that holds request data by calling the GetRequestStream method. 
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        // Write the data to the request stream. 
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); 
        // Close the Stream object. 
        dataStream.Close();
```

Cualquier ayuda se los agradecería, si necesitan mas información, por favor, me lo hagan saber

Answer (score 0):

A mi me funciono agregando:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

Que indica el protocolo TLS 1.2. Tenes que ponerlo al principio de tu código.

Comment: Por favor, agrega más detalles para ampliar tu respuesta, como código que funcione o citas de documentación.